# Error: Generated SELECT statement. Syntax Error: Expecting

Tags: visual-studio-2008, query-builder

My SQL is below along with the error above it. I dont know what the problem is anymore. Ive tried so much. Can somebody please help?

> Error : Generated SELECT statement
>           Syntax Error : Expecting ',' or 'FROM' after column alias or '*'
>       To add these components to your dataset, click Finish.

```
SELECT ALCIE.POLINE.DISTDIV
    , ALCIE.POLINE.DISTDEPT
    , ALCIE.POLINE.DISTGL
    , ALCIE.POLINE.LINENO
    , ALCIE.POLINE.ITEM
    , ALCIE.POLINE.ITEMDES1
    , ALCIE.POLINE.ITEMDES2
    , ALCIE.POLINE.PO
    , ALCIE.POLINE.PODATE
    , ALCIE.POLINE.PURCHUOM
    , ALCIE.POLINE.QTYORD
    , ALCIE.POLINE.CUMQTYREC
    , ALCIE.POLINE.UNITCOST
    , ALCIE.POLINE.CUMQTYREC * ALCIE.POLINE.UNITCOST AS EXPR1
    , ALCIE.POLINE.RECDATE
    , ALCIE.POLINE.VENDOR
    , ALCIE.APMASTER.NAME1
    , ALCIE.POLINE.STATUS
    , ALCIE.POHEADER.STATUS AS EXPR2
    , ALCIE.POLINE.STKLOC
    , ALCIE.POLINE.LAST_REC_USERID
    , ALCIE.POLINE.ITEMDES3
    , 'ALCIE_POLINE.PO' || 'ALCIE_POLINE.LINENO' AS EXPR3
    , ALCIE.POHEADER.COMMENTS4
FROM ALCIE.POLINE, ALCIE.POHEADER, ALCIE.APMASTER
WHERE ALCIE.POLINE.CO = ALCIE.POHEADER.CO 
    AND ALCIE.POLINE.PO = ALCIE.POHEADER.PO 
    AND ALCIE.POHEADER.CO = ALCIE.APMASTER.CO 
    AND ALCIE.POHEADER.VENDOR = ALCIE.APMASTER.VENDOR 
    AND (ALCIE.POLINE.CO = 'WSA') 
    AND (ALCIE.POLINE.PO = :EnterPoNumber)
ORDER BY ALCIE.POLINE.ITEMDES1, ALCIE.POLINE.PO
```

Comment: include the create table for these tables: ALCIE.POLINE, ALCIE.POHEADER, ALCIE.APMASTER

Comment: I would strongly advise the use of aliases, it would help with code readability.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ALCIE.POLINE.DISTDIV, 
ALCIE.POLINE.DISTDEPT, 
ALCIE.POLINE.DISTGL, 
ALCIE.POLINE.LINENO, 
ALCIE.POLINE.ITEM, 
ALCIE.POLINE.ITEMDES1, 
ALCIE.POLINE.ITEMDES2, 
ALCIE.POLINE.PO, 
ALCIE.POLINE.PODATE, 
ALCIE.POLINE.PURCHUOM, 
ALCIE.POLINE.QTYORD, 
ALCIE.POLINE.CUMQTYREC, 
ALCIE.POLINE.UNITCOST, 
ALCIE.POLINE.CUMQTYREC * ALCIE.POLINE.UNITCOST AS EXPR1, 
ALCIE.POLINE.RECDATE, 
ALCIE.POLINE.VENDOR, 
ALCIE.APMASTER.NAME1, 
ALCIE.POLINE.STATUS, 
ALCIE.POHEADER.STATUS AS EXPR2, 
ALCIE.POLINE.STKLOC, 
ALCIE.POLINE.LAST_REC_USERID, 
ALCIE.POLINE.ITEMDES3, 
(ALCIE.POLINE.PO | ALCIE.POLINE.LINENO) AS EXPR3, 
ALCIE.POHEADER.COMMENTS4
FROM ALCIE.POLINE, ALCIE.POHEADER, ALCIE.APMASTER
WHERE ALCIE.POLINE.CO = ALCIE.POHEADER.CO 
    AND ALCIE.POLINE.PO = ALCIE.POHEADER.PO 
    AND ALCIE.POHEADER.CO = ALCIE.APMASTER.CO 
    AND ALCIE.POHEADER.VENDOR = ALCIE.APMASTER.VENDOR 
    AND (ALCIE.POLINE.CO = 'WSA') 
    AND (ALCIE.POLINE.PO = :EnterPoNumber)
ORDER BY ALCIE.POLINE.ITEMDES1, ALCIE.POLINE.PO
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was on the select statement, You need to convert all your calculations to `TO_NUMBER` as follows:

Try this:

```
SELECT
   TO_NUMBER(TABLE_NAME.COLUMN * TABLE_NAME.COLUMN) AS EXPR1, 
   TO_NUMBER(TABLE_NAME.COLUMN * 100) AS EXPR2
FROM TABLE_NAME
```